# applying filtering to a groupby function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a group of cells that can have many antennas at different heights. I need to build a dataframe that contains cells that have more than 1 antenna but at different heights

I have tried to use the groupby function, which returns me the count of the cells but I cant work out how to filter with it

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame( { 
    "Cell" : ["AAAA", "BBBB","BBBB","CCCC","CCCC","DDDD","DDDD"] , 
    "antenna" : ["A1", "A1","A1","A2","A4","A1","A2"] ,
    "height": ["5","30","30","45","45","30","15"] ,
    "function": 
["LTE1800","LTE700","LTE700","LTE700","LTE700","LTE2100","LTE2100"]} )

df1['count'] = df1.groupby('Cell')['Cell'].transform('count')
```

which returns:

```
    Cell    antenna height  function    count
0   AAAA    A1      5       LTE1800     1
1   BBBB    A1      30      LTE700      2
2   BBBB    A1      30      LTE700      2
3   CCCC    A2      45      LTE700      2
4   CCCC    A4      45      LTE700      2
5   DDDD    A1      30      LTE2100     2
6   DDDD    A2      15      LTE2100     2
```

The output I want is:

```
    Cell    antenna height  function    count
1   DDDD    A1      30      LTE2100     2
2   DDDD    A2      15      LTE2100     2
```

or conversely:

```
    Cell    antenna height  function    count
0   AAAA    A1      5       LTE1800     1
1   BBBB    A1      30      LTE700      2
2   BBBB    A1      30      LTE700      2
3   CCCC    A2      45      LTE700      2
4   CCCC    A4      45      LTE700      2
```

I have had limited experiences with groupby queries so I have no idea how I can accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `transform` with `nunique`

```
g=df1.groupby('Cell')
df1[g.antenna.transform('nunique').eq(2)&g.height.transform('nunique').eq(2)]
   Cell antenna height function
5  DDDD      A1     30  LTE2100
6  DDDD      A2     15  LTE2100
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter basically runs a function on each group in your groupby:

```
df1[df1['count']>1].groupby('Cell').filter(lambda x: x.height.nunique() > 1)
   Cell antenna height function  count
5  DDDD      A1     30  LTE2100      2
6  DDDD      A2     15  LTE2100      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might be to calculcate the standard deviation of the antenna height (`height_std`) as a measure for the variation of the heights and then select only those rows with non-zero standard deviations (if all heights are the same, the standard deviation is zero):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Cell": ["AAAA", "BBBB", "BBBB", "CCCC", "CCCC", "DDDD", "DDDD"],
    "antenna": ["A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A4", "A1", "A2"],
    "height": ["5", "30", "30", "45", "45", "30", "15"],
    "function":
    ["LTE1800", "LTE700", "LTE700", "LTE700", "LTE700", "LTE2100", "LTE2100"]})

df1.height = df1.height.astype(int)
df1['height_std'] = df1.groupby('Cell').height.transform('std')

print(df1[df1['height_std'] > 0])
#   Cell antenna function  height  height_std
#5  DDDD      A1  LTE2100      30   10.606602
#6  DDDD      A2  LTE2100      15   10.606602
```

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want to a `group by` and a `having` if this were SQL, you can achieve that like so:

```
df1.groupby(['Cell'], as_index=False).filter(lambda g: g['height'].nunique() >= 2)

   Cell antenna height function
5  DDDD      A1     30  LTE2100
6  DDDD      A2     15  LTE2100


df1.groupby(['Cell'], as_index=False).filter(lambda g: g['height'].nunique() < 2)

   Cell antenna height function
0  AAAA      A1      5  LTE1800
1  BBBB      A1     30   LTE700
2  BBBB      A1     30   LTE700
3  CCCC      A2     45   LTE700
4  CCCC      A4     45   LTE700
```